# Passing connection string to dll?

Tags: .net, dll, shared-libraries, app-config

I am trying to make some simple libraries that require database access. What I don't get is how to pass the connection string to the library... Right now I have a db.config in my dll, but I'm not sure how to reference it from within the dll etc...

This is how I have setup the libraries

**[Solution File]**

- Library1

  - db.config
- Library2

  - linked db.config

```
<configuration>
        <!-- Connection string -->
    </configuration>
```

1. How do I reference the db.config from within dll?
2. How do I reference the db.config from a web applications web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real simple:

1) If this happens to be a .Net .dll, you can store it in "app.config" or "web.config":

[Example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45321-grabbing-connectionstring-from-appconfig/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DigiBrd"
           connectionString="server=localhost;user id=****;Password=****;database=DigiBrd"
           providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

String cnString =
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DigiBrd"].ConnectionString;
```

2) You can also store the connection string anywhere that the .dll can read it.  For example, you can use an .ini file or the registry.

3) You can implement a `getConnectionString()` method in your .dll.

4) Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a config file?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question:

I usually prefer to use one of the ConfigurationManager methods like this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx

Or there is the old style Xml with XPath:

```
XmlDocument webConfig = new XmlDocument();
webConfig.Load(dllConfigFileName);
XmlNode someNode = webConfig.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key='someKey']");
```

Or the newer LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(configFileFullName);
XElement configurationElement = document.Element("configuration");
XElement appSettingsElement = configurationElement.Element("appSettings");
List<XElement> configSettings = new List<XElement>(appSettingsElement.Descendants("add"));
```

Comment: Is the config file you are referencing in the library or the application calling the library? Right now I have a conStrings.config file in my application and in the class library I call it using string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectMain"].ToString(); but this doesn't seem like that great of an idea.

Comment: My code just shows how to load up and consume any config file.